# Questions about finitely generated nilpotent groups

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated

Suppose $G$ is a nilpotent group of class $c$, where $c > 1$. This means that if we define the lower central series by $l_1(G) = G$ and $l_k(G) = [G,l_{k-1}(G)]$ for $k \geqslant 2$, then $l_{c+1} (G) = {1}$, while $l_c(G)$ is nontrivial. Suppose also that $G$ is generated by the elements $x_1,...,x_n$. Now I have a couple of questions about this group.

1) Consider an element $h \in l_c(G)$. How to show that there are elements $g_i$ of $l_{c-1}(G)$ for $i=1,...,n$ such that 
$$
h = \prod_1^n [x_i, g_i].
$$

2) Can we invent something like induction to show that actually an arbitrary element $h\in [G,G]$ can be expressed as a such product where $g_i \in G$?

Also, a good reference on this subject would be really nice. I have never done such things before, so I do not have any good ideas on what to do actually, so sorry if this is a really dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the convention $x^y = y^{-1}xy$, $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$. Then using the standard commutator identities:

If $g_1,g_2 \in G$ and $h \in L_{c-1}(G)$, then $[g_1g_2,h] = [g_1,h]^{g_2}[g_2,h] = [g_1,h][g_2,h]$, since $[g_1,h] \in Z(G)$.

Similarly, for $g \in G$, $h_1,h_2 \in H$, $[g,h_1h_2]= [g,h_2][g,h_1]^{h_2} = [g,h_1][g,h_2]$.

(This shows that the commutator map $G \times L_{c-1}(G) \to L_c(G)$ is bilinear.)

It follows from this that if $G = \langle x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n \rangle$ and $L_{c-1}(G) = \langle y_1,\ldots,y_m \rangle$, then $L_c(G)  = \langle [x_i,y_j] \mid 1 \le i \le n,\, 1 \le j \le m \rangle$.

So each element of $L_c(G)$ can be written as product of elements of the form $[x_i,y_j]^{\pm 1} = [x_i,y_j^{\pm 1}]$. They all commute and, for each fixed $i$, you can group all of the $[x_i,y_j]$ terms together and replace them by a single term $[x_i,g_i]$, which answers Question (1).

This argument shows that the images of  $[x_i,x_j]$ generate $L_2(G)/L_3(G)$, and then that the images of $[x_i,[x_j,x_k]]$ generate $L_3(G)/L_4(G)$, etc, and so you can conclude that each $L_i(G)$ is finitely generated.

We can prove Qn (2) by induction on $c$. It is trivial for $c=1$.
Assume that $c>1$, and let $h \in G'$.

Applying (2) inductively to $G/L_c(G)$, there exist $g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_n \in G$ and $h' \in L_c(G)$ with $g = [x_1,g_1][x_2,g_2] \cdots [x_n,g_n]h'$.

Them applying Qn (1) to $h'$, there exist $h_1,\ldots,h_n \in L_{c-1}(G)$ with $g = [x_1,h_1][x_2,h_2] \cdots [x_n,h_n]$. Since the commutators $[x_i,h_i]$ all lie in $Z(G)$, we have

$$g = \prod_{i=1}^n [x_i,g_i][x_i,h_i] =\prod_{i=1}^n [x_i,g_i][x_i,h_i]^{g_i}= \prod_{i=1}^n [x_i,h_ig_i],$$

which proves (2).

Comment: First of all, as I understand, there must be $g_2$ instead of $y$ in the second paragraph. Second, why is this commutator lies in a center of a whole group?

Comment: Thank you, that was easy!

Comment: Is it necessary the case that $G/L_c(G)$ is nilpotent of the class less than $c$?

Comment: Well, I suppose we can argue on the fact that $L_c(G)$ is in the kernel of projection $G \rightarrow G/Z(G)$.

Comment: $G/L_c(G)$ has class exactly $c-1$, because $L_k(G/L_c(G)) = L_k(G)/L_c(G)$ for $k \le c$. But in general, $Z(G)$ could be larger than $L_c(G)$.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for the explanation! The argument on the projection actually works as well :)

Answer (score 1):

By definition:

$$l_c(G):=[G,l_{c-1}(G)]:=\langle [x,y]\;;\;x\in G\,,\,y\in l_{c-1}(G)\rangle$$

so question (1) is just definition...and so it's question 2, of course.

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see why that answers question (1) (and question (2), for that matter). The fact that an element from $l_c(G)$ can be expressed by a product of elements $[x,y]$ with $x\in G$ and $y\in l_{c-1}(G)$ does not (at least not easily) imply that this product can always be chosen to be of length $n$ and contain $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ (in that order) as values for $x$.

Comment: The reason that it answers question (1) is that the commutator map $G \times L_{c-1}(G) \to L_c(G)$ defined by $(x,y) \mapsto [x,y]$ is bilinear. This follows from the commutator identities and the fact that $L_c(G) \le Z(G)$. I am not about Question (2).

Comment: @DerekHolt sorry, can you provide more details on this argument?